# C: Read function does not return error on disconnected serial USB device

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have a C application which opens a /dev/ttyUSB* port

```
    fd = open(portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_iflag &= (tcflag_t) ~(INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IGNBRK);
    options.c_oflag &= (tcflag_t) ~(OPOST);
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
    struct serial_struct kernel_serial_settings;
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &kernel_serial_settings) == 0) {
                kernel_serial_settings.flags |= ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY;
                kernel_serial_settings..
                ioctl(fd, TIOCSSERIAL, &kernel_serial_settings);
    }
```

The port is opened, and I receive data. If however the USB device is disconnected later on, and I call the read function:

```
nRead = _read(fd, buffer, length);
```

nRead will return 0. I would expect that it should return a negative number to indicate an error (that the device is no longer available).

How do I detect that the opened device was disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [read()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) returns zero, you can call [stat()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on the device filename.  If the USB device is disconnected, the device node has vanished, and stat() will return -1 with errno==ENOENT.

Comment: @ryyker I think it does - the question is literally "How do I detect that the opened device was disconnected?"   If `stat()` errors out with `ENOENT`, that literally means "it's not there".  Since it **was** there earlier, and now it's not, "disconnected" is a pretty good inference to make from that result.  And you can probably just use `fstat()` on the file descriptor.  It's analogous to getting `0` from `read()` when a TCP connection gets disconnected.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Thanks.  Good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`stat()` on the device file name is not safe,
there may appear other devices connected to USB.

Better is to check `fstat( fd, &stat )`.
**stat.st_nlink** drops to zero when the device is disconnected from USB.
All device permissions also drop to zero.
It is not a perfect method, because there is a few millisecond delays with this field to be changed after disconnect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).